# I can't insert into table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-insert

I created a stored procedure which has two statements `insert` and `update`.

It gets two parameters:

```
@content as nvarchar(10),
@fieldName as int
```

In `Update` line everything works correctly, but it doesn't insert to table.
Syntax and everything is true but when I execute

```
Execute sp_update 432,4
```

SQL Server shows this error:

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Invalid column name 'up'.
>
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Invalid column name 'Field3'.*

This is my script:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_update]
    @content as nvarchar(10),
    @fieldName as int
as
   declare @ff as varchar
   set @ff = Convert(varchar,@fieldName)

   declare @f as char(7) 
   set @f = 'Field'+ @ff

   declare @sqlupdate varchar(500)
   declare @sqlinserttoChangelog varchar(500)

   set @sqlinserttoChangelog = 'Insert Into dbo.changelog (changeType, fieldname) Values ('+'up'+','+@f+')'
   Exec (@sqlinserttoChangelog)

   set @sqlupdate = 'update TableTest set ' + @f + ' = '+@Content
   Exec (@sqlupdate)
```

Comment: Side note: string to be executed by `EXEC` should always be of type `NVARCHAR` - since that's what `EXEC` expects. In your case, you're causing an implicit conversion from `varchar` to `nvarchar` which (a) costs time and effort, and (b) could lead to really hard to find bugs if you ever use non-ANSI characters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are creating *dynamic sql*, the values should be wrap with single quote. To escape single quote, it must be doubled, eg.

```
set @sqlinserttoChangelog = 'Insert Into dbo.changelog (changeType, fieldname) Values ('''+'up'+''', '+@f+')'
```

same with the `content`

```
set @sqlupdate = 'update TableTest set ' + @f + ' = '''+ @Content + ''''
```